# That was my father or that is my father?

Tags: tense, grammaticality-in-context

Suppose you were talking to your friend, in a casual conversation.
Friend: Was that your father whom we saw yesterday at the school?
You: Yes, that was my father.

I'm quite confused whether to use "that is my father" or "that was my father".

I feel it should be "that is my father", because the question establishes the fact that my father was seen in the school yesterday and be it today, tomorrow, a week or a month later, he's still going to he my father.

Answer (score 1):

Both are possible. In the context you give "was" is probably more likely to be used. The question has established a past tense, and we are talking about a past event (the visit of a person to school yesterday).

Your question and answer are very far from "casual conversation" in style.  They are highly formal.  Don't use "whom" or "father" in casual conversation.

> Was that your dad we saw at school yesterday?
> Yeah, that was him.

Answer (score 0):

The question is, "**Was** that your father?", so the answer is, "Yes that **was** my father."  Or, of course, it could be, "No, that wasn't my father."

Here is a present-tense example.

**Is** that your father standing over there?  Yes that **is** my father.